# Modern implementations of russian programming language "Rapira "?

Tags: programming-languages

Are there modern (later than 1990) implementations of russian "Rapira" programming language?

Wikipedia mentioned none.

Answer (score 2):

This question brings back the memories of 1980s and exercises in Rapira procedural programming popularized by [Quantum magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kvant_magazine). However, I don't believe there are any recent implementations of this language.

The latest one I was able to find for a non-Soviet PC is a 1983 implementation for Apple Macintosh. (source: [Technical note by Academician Andrei Ershov](http://ershov.iis.nsk.su/archive/eaimage.asp?lang=2&did=7242&fileid=109747))

Out of curiousity, other than doing research in history of computing, why would you need it these days?

Answer (score 0):

ReRap is a Russian and English Rapira implementation.