# Programming in a language other than English

Tags: unicode, programming-languages, syntax, multilingual

I was having a discussion on twitter about adding the ability of Ruby to use `λ` instead of `lambda`, and more generally about Unicode support.  I realized that all the languages I know work only with English reserved words and mostly assume a us-en keyboard (for example using $ instead of £ or ¥).  While some languages are now starting to have some support for Unicode in there string functions, there are still so many convention based on English or the Latin style character set.  For example Ruby requires class names begin with an upper case letter, but upper and lower case is not a property of glyphs in most scripts.

So the question is: "Are there programming languages that work in a large set of languages, and how do they do it?"

Comment: Take a look at the **related** links, on the right of this page ;-)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but remembered [rapira](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368455/modern-implementations-of-russian-programming-language-rapira), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapira)...

Comment: (1) English language != ASCII character set. Period. (2) Note that this is not necessarily a bad thing. I can't type hungarian letters on my german keyboard (so I couldn't use stuff from a library with hungarian names), and hungarians can't type german umlauts on their keyboards (vice versa to the previous) - but about every keyboard includes the ASCII character set (so everyone can use ASCII-only identifiers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look ant the [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) programming language, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Some languages define very simple syntaxes and little or no keyworks. For example, LISPs and languages that function like them (Tcl, etc...) where everything is "command arg1 ... argn". These languages, since there are no keywords per se, are language agnostic.

For example, in Tcl, you can rename the various commands to use whatever language you want and everything should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 is completely Unicode-based, so identifiers can be constructed out of any Unicode letters/digits etc.

It's still not a good idea to use characters for function names that programmers from other nations don't have easy access to on their keyboards.

Comment: Still, all pythons reserve words and standard library are in English sure you could name a variable κύριε_ἐλέησον but you would still need to know English to do anything productive.

Comment: Its a matter of least common denominator: (1) You can type US ascii on most keyboards you can get. (2) Imagine some chinese guys wrote a useful utility library and named everything chinese - you would very likely be lost. (3) The language of science was agreed upon to be english - whether that's a good or bad choice is subject to discussion but you need one common language to communicate with each other and english is easy enough to learn (read and write).

Answer (score 0):

In the [3.0.0  release](http://www.parrot.org/news/2011/parrot-3.0.0) of the Parrot VM, they added support for a language, [Ωη;)XD](https://github.com/plobsing/ohm-eta-wink-kzd#readme) that is named using unicode which caused all kinds of breakage for the VM. It might be worth taking a look at.